# How to combine a different strings under one single cell array in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have data in different cells (mostly strings) and I would like to bring some of the data in one cell and keep the rest of the data as it is.

For instance:

```
A = {'1' '2' '3' '4' '5'; '6' '7' '8' '9' '10'; '11' '12' '13' '14' '15'};
```

The desired output should be:

```
B = {'1' '2' '3 4 5'; '6' '7' '8 9 10'; '11' '12' '13 14 15'};
```

The numbers must be separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using string and join in 16b makes this a bit easier than using strjoin since join works with the dimensionality of matrices.

```
>> A = string({'1' '2' '3' '4' '5'; '6' '7' '8' '9' '10'; '11' '12' '13' '14' '15'});
>> [A(:,1:2) join(A(:,3:end),2)]

ans = 

  3×3 string array

    "1"     "2"     "3 4 5"   
    "6"     "7"     "8 9 10"  
    "11"    "12"    "13 14 15"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c{1} = 'a'
c{2} = 'b'
c{3} = 'c'
>> c{2} = 'b'
c = 
  'a'    'b'    'c'
>> {char(c)'}
ans = 
    'abc'
>> {strjoin(c, ' ')}
ans = 
    'a b c'
```

Comment: I think you need a `cellfun` to make this answer complete :)

Comment: @GameOfThrows: I have difficulty in understanding that what is missing in solution. Please add your solution if you think it is not complete solution

Comment: The solution which you have given works partially. I mean, I want to club that data in the same table. Your solution is creating a different cell array with the name `ans`. I want it under the same variable name, in your case `c`

Answer (score 0):

Use the strjoin method.

```
strjoin(A(1,1:3))
returns '1 2 3'
```

// Automatically has spaces.

This MATLAB method defaults to a space delimeter. However....
If you should need an additional delimeter use this

```
strjoin(A(1,1:3),'*')
returns '1*2*3'


B = A(:,1:2);
  for count = 1:size(A)
     B(count,3)=cellstr(strjoin(A(count,3:5)));
  end
```

This is how I would do what you wanted above.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone here has MATLAB prior to R2013a (which does not have `strjoin()`) or R2013b (which does not have `join()`):

```
% The original
A = { '1'  '2'  '3'  '4'  '5'
      '6'  '7'  '8'  '9' '10'
     '11' '12' '13' '14' '15'};

% The new
B = A;
B(:,3) = strcat(arrayfun(@(ii) sprintf('%s ', B{ii,3:end-1}), 1:size(B,1), 'UniformOutput', false)', ...
                B(:,end));
B(:,4:end) = []
```

which is so fugly that it only serves as a vindication for `strjoin()` :)